# Can ECC correctness issues in CVE-2015-2730 allow "remote attackers to spoof ECDSA signatures"?

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, ecc

> **CVE-2015-2730**: Mozilla Network Security Services (NSS) before 3.19.1, as used in Mozilla Firefox before 39.0, Firefox ESR 31.x before 31.8 and 38.x before 38.1, and other products, does not properly perform Elliptical Curve Cryptography (ECC) multiplications, which makes it easier for remote attackers to spoof ECDSA signatures via unspecified vectors.
>
> The formulas appearing in ecp_jac.c do not handle the case when the addition produces infinity or adds a point to itself. An attacker can use this to generate specially-crafted signatures that cause the validation algorithm to compute the incorrect point.

For more details, please check the following link:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1125025

Could this Elliptic Curve Cryptography issue really lead to spoofed ECDSA signatures or is this purely a theoretical attack?

Could ECC correctness issues compromise security in other ways?

Comment: As you seem to be asking about the practical impact, the question seems fine here (it would actually likely be off-topic at crypto.SE). If you want to know technical details about the issue, crypto.SE would be a better fit.

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/47904/23623